# XmlSerializer and inline elements support

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Does anyone know if XmlSerializer supports inline elements?

For example, I am trying to parse something like this

```
<foo>This sample has an inline <barZ x="1" /> element <barX>.</barX></foo>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Ok, I found it...

It seems that it needs something like this

```
[XmlElement("barZ", typeof(BarZ))]
[XmlElement("barX", typeof(BarX))]
public object[] Items { get; set; }

[XmlText]
public string[] Text { get; set; }
```

The issue now is that the `Items` property keeps the elements and the `Text` the strings.
When trying to serialize it again, the initial order of the values takes no part...

Comment: Why don't you use Linq2Xml?

Comment: Why don't you try? It takes nearly the same time to try than other people need to write answers and discuss your question.

Comment: I need a specific model for my implementation. That's why I don't want an XDocument.